# What is the difference between identity and increment in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using my database in Access and I want to do an auto increment by ID.

Which one should I use?

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment().Column("COLUMN_NAME");
```

or

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("COLUMN_NAME");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) (Nhibernate is a porting of the Java Project)

> **increment**
>
> generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only
>   when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not
>   use in a cluster.
>
> **identity**
>
> supports identity columns in DB2, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Sybase and
>   HypersonicSQL. The returned identifier is of type long, short or int.
>
> **sequence**
>
> uses a sequence in DB2, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SAP DB, McKoi or a
>   generator in Interbase. The returned identifier is of type long, short
>   or int
>
> **native**
>
> selects identity, sequence or hilo depending upon the capabilities of the >underlying database.

So ***Increment*** should be used for small scenario and the increment is calculated in-memory.

***Identity\Sequence\Native*** use native functionality of the database to calculate the increment.

Since you're using Access probably you're in the first scenario, but I suggest you to migrate to MS SQL Server Express for better performance, security, usability and scaling. It's free and the migration should be painless.

Comment: NHibernate own documentation is on http://nhibernate.info/ and more precisely for id generator, [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator).